# Run a Git synchronization batch file at Windows shutdown

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, shutdown

I am trying to automatically run a batch file which synchronizes a directory in git when shutdown.

batch file content:

```bash
cd C:\"Program Files"\dawData
git init
git add -u
git add .
git commit -m "Cambios realizados el $(date +"%Y-%m-%d")"
git push
```

It works perfectly by itself, but the problem how do I run it at shutdown.

I have tried many things in the Task Scheduler and the Local Group Policy Editor.

The last thing that I tried in the Task Scheduler was:

[Task scheduler attemp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Ndz.jpg)

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should include the image directly and translate because otherwise very few will be able to help you. This thing aside, your script seems strange : why do you try to init a new repository?

Comment: Doing things at shutdown aren’t guaranteed to run

Comment: @Philippe Thank you for your suggestion, I just reuploaded the photo in English. About the repository, the batch file works fine by itself. It does upload the files to the cloud. The problem is that the batch is not even executed.

Comment: @DanielA.White, thanks you for your comment. Do you think its not safe upload files to git by executing a batch in shutdown?